# Notify users if their account is going to expire in 5 days later - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are many users buying premium account in my website. How can i select users in which their account expiration day is exactly in 5 days later and notify them about renew account ?

in `app\console\kernel.php` add below function but dont know how to code about time in query.

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 */

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();
    $schedule->call(function () {

        $users = User::where('expiration_time', '=', Carbon::now()->addDays(5))->get();

        //Notify related user about account emigrations
        Notification::send($users, new AccountExpiration());

    })->daily();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, the only one thing that could cause your query from failing is your datebase table column type.

If your **expiration_time** column type is DATE you should use

```
Carbon::now()->addDays(5)->toDateString()
```

If your **expiration_time** column type is DATETIME you should use

```
Carbon::now()->addDays(5)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Get the users in between today and 5 days later.

```
User::whereBetween('expiration_time', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDays(5)])->get();
```

OR alternatively

```
User::whereBetween('expiration_time', [date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 days"))])->get();
```